# The adding up of numbers isn't working right in my food ordering system

Tags: python

```
prices=print("Mushroom Pies:£1.20     Vegtable Pies:£0.80     Spiced Lentil Pies:£1.40")
vegetablepies=0.80
mushroompies=1.20
spicedpies=1.40
total=vegetablepies+mushroompies+spicedpies
vegetablepies=input("How many vegtable pies do you want?")
mushroompies=input("How many mushroom pies do you want?")
spicedpies=input("How many spiced lentil pies do you want?")
print(total)
```

This is my code i have been working on it for a bit but this one part doesn't work and I'm unsure why the maths isn't working

Comment: why you calculate `total` before asking it from user ?!

Answer (score 1):

Your ordering of code is backwards. You want to ask for inputs first, then calculate the total after that. Move the line calculating the total after all three inputs like so:

```
vegetablepies=input("How many vegtable pies do you want?")
mushroompies=input("How many mushroom pies do you want?")
spicedpies=input("How many spiced lentil pies do you want?")
total=vegetablepies+mushroompies+spicedpies
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you want:

```
prices = print('Mushroom Pies:£1.20     Vegtable Pies:£0.80     Spiced Lentil Pies:£1.40')

vegetablepies_price = 0.80
mushroompies_price = 1.20
spicedpies_price = 1.40

vegetablepies = input('How many vegetable pies do you want?')
mushroompies = input('How many mushroom pies do you want?')
spicedpies = input('How many spiced lentil pies do you want?')

total_pies = int(vegetablepies) + int(mushroompies) + int(spicedpies)
total_price = int(vegetablepies)*vegetablepies_price + int(mushroompies)*mushroompies_price + int(spicedpies)*spicedpies_price

print('Total Pies:',total_pies)
print('Total Cost: £{:.2f}'.format(total_price))
```

This code multiplies the price of the item by the number of items, and then returns the total cost of the order. In order to add up the numbers that the user inputs, you need to convert them from a string to a number. I used `int()`, which will force the numbers to be integers (assuming you can't order half a pie).